# Ms sql деление стобца на два

Tags: sql, запрос-в-запросе

Добрый день.

```
SELECT Report.PrintDate,Information.Grup, FORMAT(Report.Sum,'N') AS 'Sum'
FROM Report INNER JOIN Information ON Report.id_info = Information.id
WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '15.08.2017' AND '25.08.2017' AND Information.Grup = 'Москва, ТЦ Л-153, ул. Любинская, 153'
ORDER BY Report.PrintDate,Report.ID
```

Данный запрос выводит таблицу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя задача получить с помощью запроса такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просьба помочь, не пойму возможно ли это вообще

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обрамляете значение в условие, при котором его нужно выводить, и получите нужный результат. Можно использовать функцию sign, можно сравнивать с нулем - вариантов много.

```
SELECT Report.PrintDate,Information.Grup
     , case sign(Report.Sum) 
          when -1 then FORMAT(Report.Sum,'N') 
          else '' end AS 'Minus'
     , case sign(Report.Sum) 
          when 1 then FORMAT(Report.Sum,'N') 
          else '' end AS 'Plus'
FROM Report 
     INNER JOIN Information ON Report.id_info = Information.id
WHERE PrintDate BETWEEN '15.08.2017' AND '25.08.2017' 
  AND Information.Grup = 'Москва, ТЦ Л-153, ул. Любинская, 153'
ORDER BY Report.PrintDate,Report.ID
```